# initializing multiple jQuery plugins using a Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am a `Angular` noob, so please forgive the ignorance riddling this post.

**Details:**

I am using `CodeIgniter` with `Angular.js` and I am stumbling over the concept of initializing many plugins in my application. I have about 5 plugins that I want to use ( dropdowns, sliders, etc).

**Question:**

I have seen examples online on how to init a plugin, something like this:

```
embroidery.directive( 'f-foundation', function() {
    return {
            restrict: 'A', 
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
            // each element is needing a explicit init
            element.foundation( 'dropdown', 'start' );
        }   
    }
});
```

That directive would be applied to the dropdown element like so:

```
<select f-foundation>
    <option>test infomation</option>
</select>
```

This would require be to init EACH plugin in different directives; there has to be a better way.

But, I am wondering if there is a way that I can have all my plugins init as the same time. If I wasn't using Angular I would have a simple `plugin_init()` function filled with

```
$( element ).chosen();
$( element_2 ).toolbar();
$( document ).foundation(); //etc
```

Am I missing a concept with Angular? Any help?

Comment: What's the necessity of initializing all of the plugins at once is it a landing page type site? Otherwise you can use the directives and initialize when needed instead of all at once maybe even use requirejs to only load the needed plugin source unless this is a simple one page type site

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are missing a concept. Actually the concept is separation of concerns.

Right now it might seem an overkill, only to initialize the plugins, but on the long run it gives you the flexibility to expand your directives. It seems like an overkill because you are not passing any options to the plugin initialization, but as the application grows, every instance has a different configuration.

Maybe it will help you to think of your directive as an adapter between your markup and the specific plugin you are using. If you ever had to change the plugin (i.e. `chosen` => `select2`), you would only need to rewrite the directive content.

**EDIT**: After some thought, I dunno the size and scope of the app you are building. Maybe **it is** and overkill. In which case, don't initialize them using angular just do it as you suggested. I can only advise you to don't do it using directives if it's a one page marketing site with a contact form, other than that you be the judge.